# Retrieve username, password parameters passed through curl

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I am trying to send username and password parameters to a url using curl, and I want to retrieve them. I send the parameters to a page, like the following:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init('http://localhost/sample.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);                         
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'key:123456');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);                    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);                          
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);                           
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Sample Code');

$response = curl_exec($curl);                                          
$resultStatus = curl_getinfo($curl);                                   

if($resultStatus['http_code'] == 200) {
    echo $response;
} else {
    echo 'Call Failed '.print_r($resultStatus);                         
}
?>
```

Now in the sample.php page, how can I retrieve those parameters?
(here, username is key, password is 123456).

I suppose they must be available in the $_SERVER array, but they are not available.

Comment: Which parameters? You don't send any parameter

Comment: Iam sending username and password in the line: CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'key:123456'. Now how can i retrieve them?

Comment: Got it now. Iam running php as CGI. So this wont work directly. Refer: http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/http-auth-php-cgi.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, cURL issues an HTTP GET request. In this case, you'd have to append the parameters to the URL you're calling:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://localhost/sample.php?foo=bar&baz=zoid');
```

In `sample.php`, `$_GET['bar']` and `$_GET['baz']` would be available respectively. If it's a POST request, you want to issue, you'll need to set the parameters via `curl_setopt`:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://localhost/sample.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'foo=bar&baz=zoid');
```

Comment: Now how can i retrieve the username and password in my page?

Comment: @dskanth Dump `$_SERVER`. All "parameters" passed through the header from cURL are present there.

Comment: But iam not getting the PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PW parameters in the $_SERVER array, however i got AUTH_TYPE. Do i need to setup usernames and passwords in .htpasswd file and maintain a .htaccess file?

Comment: @dskanth Yes, you'd have to set up Apache to actually *ask* for a username and password.

Comment: I have setup a .htaccess file and also .htpasswd file. Now whenever i access any page on my server, i get a login dialog box, and though i enter the correct credentials, i still get the same dialog box.

Comment: @dskanth Check Apache's error log. Or ask why that happens on serverfault.com

Comment: I see a message like: user not found

Answer (score 2):

Some of the parameters, like `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` are send in the HTTP headers and can be retrieved using special globals like `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` (see http://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php).

Others, like `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` are only local to CURL and don't get send to the server.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply... iam sending one of the parameters in my request like: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'key:123456'); Can i catch this, like other parameters

Comment: These should be available in `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`.

Comment: Hi, iam not able to get these values using the syntax you have given. I have this setting: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); Still the $_SERVER array does not contain those indices. AUTH_TYPE is available in the array though.

Comment: FYI, iam using Apache (bundled with Zend) on Windows.

Comment: Got it... posted my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942417/curl-http-authentication-with-zend

Answer (score 1):

to send parameters to a web page you can use 1 of two methods GET or POST

GET is where the parameters are appended to the name of the resource you are getting

e.g `$url = "http://localhost/sample.php?name=" . urlencode( $value )`

the other choice is via a POST. post is sent to the server as a page of information to do this with curl you create a post with

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'name=' . urlencode( $value ) . '&name2=' . urlencode( $value2 ));`

If on the other hand you are talking about Headers, then you can access them through the `$_SERVER['headername']` array.

DC

Comment: Please specify how can i access the username and password parameters i send through curl. FYI, iam using "ANY" type of authentication, not basic.

Comment: Are you requesting those parameters? curl wont send them if its not needed. see here how to imitate http auth with php http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: If you are using the webservers auth system (.htaccess) those parameters wont be passed through to the script the webserver will strip them out

Comment: Iam not requesting them... the link you provided opens a dialog box for entering the username and password... cant i send those values using curl?

Answer (score 1):

you can find the username and password in the global `$_SERVER` array

```
$_SERVER : array
(
     ....
    'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'the_username'
    'PHP_AUTH_PW' => 'the_password'
)
```