# Retrieve username and password in curl authentication

Tags: php, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve username, password parameters passed through curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932436/retrieve-username-password-parameters-passed-through-curl)

Hi, I am using curl for authentication, and I am sending the username and password to a curl page like this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'john:12345');
```

And I have the authentication type set to ANY:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
```

Now I want to know how can i retrieve the username and password in my php page.
When I use: `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`, I am not getting any value.

---

Full code for reference:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://localhost/pt/public/api/v1/tags.xml');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);                         
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:mypwd');

// $data = array('name' => 'Foo');
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);                    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);                          
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);                           
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Sample Code');

$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

Controller:

```
public function getAction()
{
print_r($_SERVER);
}
```

I've seen [HTTP Authentication with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) in the PHP Manual, but none of the `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` will appear.

Comment: try to debug by authentication manually from browser (not by curl) and printing $_SERVER array

Comment: In the same php file, where iam sending curl request, i put print_r($_SERVER) at the end, but i could not see the username and password in the list.

Comment: Does anyone know more about it?

Comment: wont work in cgi version of php

Comment: @Arne any source on that? All I can see in [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) is a reference to a very specific issue in PHP < 4.3.3 on IIS