# curl http authentication with Zend

Tags: php, http, zend-framework, curl

i used Zend Rest Controller for developing a web service, and now i need to authenticate users before they can access my page.

For this, iam planning to use HTTP Authentication with curl, like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");
```

And i call that curl page like this:

```
curl -u myusername:mypassword http://localhost/controller/action/page.xml
```

I have a big doubt.

Do i need to store the usernames and passwords in a .htpasswd file? If so, how do i need to retrieve parameters and validate them ?

Comment: As an alternative I also can propose you to look at OAuth as an authentication layer.

Comment: No, i actually need to send the credentials via a curl request only. FYI, iam using Apache (bundled with Zend) on Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use .htaccess the webserver will silently handle everything for you. you can assume (unless you have made a mistake) that the person is authorised.

But if you want to use http auth and get the user name and password to use in your own login system then you need to write the script thats being called like shown here.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Apart from sending through the username and password curl really has nothing to do with it. it just acts as a http client, just like a webbrowser is.

How you perform auth comes down to what you are trying to achieve. http auth is a simple authentication system.

DC

The link that I gave you shows you how to do it. The page you are calling MUST send back an authentication request otherwise curl will not forward the authentication details.

if you use a .htaccess and .htpasswd file you WILL NOT get to see the authentication because the webserver will remove those headers. If you are using a custom http auth like the one in the link I provided then you will get access to them ONLY after the auth request is sent, which means the first time the page is loaded you won't get them.

What I mean by that is.. first curl asks for the page without any credentials, if it gets the page then it stops, if it gets a request for credentials it then sends them.

This means if you want `http://localhost/controller/action/page.xml` to see the credentials then it must ask for them. if its a static page which it looks like it is, then it will not ask for the credentials.

did you mean to type `http://localhost/controller/action/page.php`

DC

the process goes like this...

```
curl                   ---> page.php (first request)
curl                   <--- page.php (first reply) "Please identify yourself" ('401 unauthorised' http code)
curl username:password ---> page.php (second request now includes user auth)
curl                   <--- page.php (second reply) ok here is the page (if id succesfull)
```

Ok as promised some working examples

first create 2 php scripts

auth.php is a modified copy of the example provided from the link I posted above

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "User name and password is required. Please try again.\n";
} else {
    // we now have access to the user and password :)
    echo "Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}\n";
    echo "You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.\n";
}

?>
```

curlfetch.php is a copy of your script from your other post

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init('http://localhost/auth.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'key:123456');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Sample Code');

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$resultStatus = curl_getinfo($curl);

if($resultStatus['http_code'] == 200) {
    echo $response;
} else {
    echo 'Call Failed '.print_r($resultStatus);
}
?>
```

create and save those scripts on your server

now test script 1 without a password

```
curl http://localhost/auth.php
```

This results in...

```
User name and password is required. Please try again.
```

Now try with a password

```
curl -u user:pass http://localhost/auth.php
```

This results in...

```
Hello user
You entered pass as your password.
```

Now try the second script, Note we don't supply a username or password as that is supplied within the script

```
curl http://localhost/curlfetch.php
```

That results in...

```
Hello key
You entered 123456 as your password.
```

Now as a reference try calling both scripts from your browser

DC

Comment: @DeveloperChris I dont see it as a silent handling. Iam sending the curl request to a php page (controller), and in that page, i need to validate the username and password from database. But i just want to know how to get those values passed through curl. They dont seem to be available in the $_SERVER array.

Comment: @DeveloperChris I meant localhost/controller/action/page.php,  and do you mean sending an authentication request is like: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
If so, then iam already adding them in the page.

Comment: No that not what I mean. when called page.php must send an auth request to the caller. in this case the caller is your curl script. I will add more to the answer to explain

Comment: @DeveloperChris Thanks for the detailed instructions... can i automate all this process by sending username and password in the first step itself (through curl)? Because i dont want to show any dialog boxes to the user. Can you post a sample code?

Comment: I still have some hopes on this... i just want to retrieve username, password and authenticate the user with curl... can anyone point me to a good example please...

Comment: @DeveloperChris I tried the above scripts from command prompt, and when i called first statement, i got the right message: User name and password is required. Please try again. But when i called: curl -u user:pass http://localhost/auth.php, i still got the same message. When i called: curl http://localhost/curlfetch.php, i got "Call Failed" message. When i tried http://localhost/auth.php from my browser, i repeatedly keep getting the login dialog box. Could not understand what is going wrong with me.

Comment: Thanks.... got it. I lately realised that the problem is with my server mode. I have php installed as CGI. Yesterday Pekka was talking to me about this in php chat session, and today I could get idea about this from here: http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/http-auth-php-cgi.html That helped me figure out the solution. I wrote that .htaccess and tried the sample script in that page, and everything worked well. Now i get those variables in $_SERVER array, & ur code works too! Thanks for all your efforts. I accept your solution. Iam pretty much satisfied, wish i could award u some points :)

Comment: Just a small twist... we have decided to validate the user credentials at the server side, not in the same file where iam sending the request. I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957002/curl-http-authentication-at-server-side

Comment: Well, iam using HTTP headers for passing the data and retrieving it like: $request->getHeader('username'); And i can retrieve the data in my controller file :)